# Calculate Sum (Total) of Column and search it by date in PHP

Tags: php, sum, subtotal

Here is sample of my sql table:

[image]

In above table:

1: **id_problem** is for user to enter an amount.

2: **id_patient** is unique ID

3: **opening_date** is about when user entered the amount.

4: **rialamount** is currency

How to **add/sum** total **rialamount** column and search it based on **opening_date** ??

For example:  User will be able to enter a date until another date to see what's the total amount..

How cal I make it by using my sql table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the column type of rialamount ??

Comment: I'm using jquery price format http://jquerypriceformat.com/

Comment: so in your database it's a varchar ? and you are storing the input generated by the jquery plugin in it? that's gonna be a problem for you, mysql don't understand this format and cannot sum it. you should store currency using [DECIMAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) (and the currency type in another column)

Comment: the problem is when I use decimal then it won't save number after decimal point, for example: 25,590.00 , it will store in decimal format mysql like this: 25   i mean numbers after decimal point won't save into column

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your mysql:

```
SELECT sum(rialamount) FROM table_name WHERE opening_date = '2015-11-07' GROUP BY opening_date;
```

Comment: I tried it, sum(rialamount)  265   , it can't get full amount for date: 2015-11-07 is Rial Amount: 265,444.99

Comment: @AlexanderRichard change the type to float(20,6) and before saving it to the database first convert it into number format

Comment: my table format type is decimal 20,6 , but it will show like this: 25.000000   even I posted question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583632/how-to-use-decimal-as-currency-mysql-table-format-type

Comment: change it to FLOAT(20,6). It will save all number formats

Comment: if you want to store US$ 25,698.20 in table then the (sum) will not work here